# What is the difference between ' @ ' and ' DECLARE ' in stored procedure?

Tags: t-sql

What is the difference between `@` and `DECLARE` in stored procedures?

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE PRO
@ID INT
@NAME NVARCHAR
AS BEGIN
DECLARE @ADDRESS NVARCHAR 
END
```

Comment: `@ID`, `@NAME` are input parameter for the stored procedure and `@ADDRESS` is local variable

Comment: Side note: declaring string variables without length creates a variable with the length of 1 char. Always specify length with string variables.

Answer (score 0):

Variable names in SQL Server starts with `@`.
A stored procedure (and a user defined function) can take in [parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/parameters?view=sql-server-2017) in the form of variables - they are simply listed with their names and data types.

Also, in stored procedures and functions, you can create local variable - for that you use the [`declare`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-local-variable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) keyword.

So in the code posted in the question, the `@Id` and `@Name` are arguments of the stored procedure while the `@Address` is a local variable.

Please note that whenever you declare a string (`char`/`nchar`/`varchar`/`nvarchar`) variable in SQL Server, you must specify the (max) length of the variable, otherwise SQL Server will default the length to 1 char.